# Bluemix container failing to network

Tags: networking, nginx, docker, ibm-cloud

When I try to assign a public IP address to a container of mine (this one is an Nginx proxy container, so I'm exposing ports 80 and 443) I've had pretty significant issues with getting the public IP address to actually work.

Sometimes it will hang while networking the container, and other times the networking will finish but the public IP address still doesn't show any content.

I decided to `cf ic exec -it nginx bash` into the container and see if I could connect to any site simply by doing something like `ping 8.8.8.8` and it fails to even connect, telling me `Destination Host Unreachable`. I'm wondering if this has something to do with the Nginx container or if anyone else has had issues networking with Bluemix Containers?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue on containers network for that tenant. In this case, only container team can assist you. So open a support request directly from your Bluemix console or you can open a new ticket here: https://support.ng.bluemix.net/gethelp/